# how to set multiple widget setting to a input box

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to add multiple attribute to one input box as follows using django.

I have tried the code as below in `forms.py`, but seems it only works for the former sentence(placeholder setting in the code below)

```
widgets = {
'content': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'What are you doing today?'}),
'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 300, 'rows': 3}),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare two different widgets for one form field. If you want a textarea with placeholder you should declare it like below.

```
widgets = {
    'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 300, 'rows': 3, 'placeholder': 'What are you doing today?'})
}
```